# Problems with visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The file got corrupted its missing some code from everywhere.

Comment: try restarting vs or your computer

Comment: still outdated even after restarting pc

Comment: maybe your vs created own fallback copy as you removed hard drive while vs wos opened, check the path if its exactly the same

Comment: @pevegaf678 -Have you tried to open other files or folders? Could you please provide us with relevant screenshots so that people can check more information. (Please overwrite personal information such as user name.)

Comment: SOrry the file got corrupted its just random letters I already rewrote the code, but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you saved the edits to the file?

VSC has a buffer for changes, so you can pick up where you left off on a file without actually saving your modifications to it. If you open the file by folder, you might skip over that cache and see what looks like an outdated version.

Comment: Where would I load them back, now I cant find the newest file anywhere

Comment: Where you mentioned if you opened the file on its own, the changes were present - inside of VSC, files with a **dot** instead of an **X** on the file tab have unsaved changes. I'd try opening it one more time and check whether your changes were saved.

Comment: sadly I was wrong the file is still outdated it has some parts that are new, but most important stuff is still gone, I also don't think I would leave it unsaved since the white ball annoys me every time I see it.